# How to analyze mac os crash report?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I am using mac os mountain lion (10.8.2) . My machine getting frequently restarting when using eclipse . After restart a popup shows `send report` . How to troubleshoot the problem using the crash report? .

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  46171 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          5
Anonymous UUID:                    2797EFBF-B052-1A79-D68C-97060E7AC0F4

Thu Dec 13 16:24:32 2012
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff800fcb7e75): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9275a439, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000800, CR3: 0x0000000023b0b018, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff8101a2d000, RCX: 0xffffff8101a2d7e8, RDX: 0x0000000000000200
RSP: 0xffffff8101ac3d00, RBP: 0xffffff8101ac3d60, RSI: 0x000000008003f000, RDI: 0xffffff8101a2d000
R8:  0xffffff8101ac3c20, R9:  0x0000000000001000, R10: 0xffffff8036a965b0, R11: 0xffffff8036a96580
R12: 0xffffff8101a2d000, R13: 0x000000008003f000, R14: 0xffffff8101a2d000, R15: 0xffffff8101a2d7e8
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff7f9275a439, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000800, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x4

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8101ac39a0 : 0xffffff800fc1d626 
0xffffff8101ac3a10 : 0xffffff800fcb7e75 
0xffffff8101ac3be0 : 0xffffff800fccd3bd 
0xffffff8101ac3c00 : 0xffffff7f9275a439 
0xffffff8101ac3d60 : 0xffffff7f9275a7f8 
0xffffff8101ac3e10 : 0xffffff7f92755428 
0xffffff8101ac3e50 : 0xffffff800ff505a0 
0xffffff8101ac3ea0 : 0xffffff800ff9a0ae 
0xffffff8101ac3f00 : 0xffffff800ffa0595 
0xffffff8101ac3f60 : 0xffffff800ffe0313 
0xffffff8101ac3fb0 : 0xffffff800fccd8ed 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.kaspersky.kext.kimul.42(42.0)[658C1759-7925-7346-A10D-B468C1BD7A1D]@0xffffff7f92753000->0xffffff7f9275cfff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kav

Mac OS version:
12C3012

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.1: Thu Oct 18 16:32:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.20.9~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 0AFA55FD-872F-3BBE-8630-214EB586A16D
Kernel slide:     0x000000000fa00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800fc00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 52214192380474
last loaded kext at 35527368584903: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f9275d000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 35660574175525: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f9275d000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.kaspersky.kext.kimul.42 42
com.kaspersky.kext.klif 2.2.1d19
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.81
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.5fc10
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.5fc10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.2f9
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.1.2f9
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.2.13
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.3d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   8.0.6
com.apple.GeForce   8.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.5.0b9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   612.20.14
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.5fc10
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.2f9
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.1.2f9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.13
com.apple.nvidia.nvGK100hal 8.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.5fc10
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.5fc10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d0
com.apple.NVDAResman    8.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.3.0d47
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   510.4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B08, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.1f173
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 384 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.14)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.2f9 11046, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS547550A9E384, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0x1d180000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0x1d182000 / 6
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821d, 0x1d181300 / 7
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0x1d183000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0x1a110000 / 3
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse, 0x0461  (Primax Electronics), 0x4d81, 0x14200000 / 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.kaspersky.kext.kimul
```

This is probably the offending kext, you'll probably want to remove it

```
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kav
```

This stands for "Kaspersky AntiVirus"; you should probably uninstall it

The rest of the stuff, like the register contents and stuff, only are useful if you know what their hexadecimal contents mean (which I don't... sorry)